# Is There a Way To Scan a UPC or QR Code from a Mobile Website?

Tags: php, html, mobile, barcode, qr-code

Is there a way to scan a UPC or QR code from a mobile website (html5 + php)?  I'm looking for a solution that would work on both iPhone and Android devices.  From what I have found, it seems that there are possibly some ways to do this on an Android by calling an installed Scanner app and using a passback URL that would pass the data back to the web app.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For Android, I would recommend using the zxing barcode library.  It's open source, and I am pretty sure it is what Google Goggles is using:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Then, you just load your website/application via a webview in Android:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

You can attach an API to the Webview that allows you to call Java code with javascript:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

I can't help much on the iOS side.  Though, I do know they have a webview available and you can probably find an open source barcode scanning library to use.

Once you write the webview "wrapper", future updates can be mostly delivered via the web since the user will just be loading your webpage, even if they think the app is native.

Comment: @John No problem!  Did you find a library for iOS?

Comment: zxing also has a C++ / iOS port, but I'm not sure a library is what's needed, as this is something that must be available from a web page. For Android, it's: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages  The iOS client from the project, Barcodes, also supports something kind of similar via "zxing://" URLs.   (Yes, Goggles uses zxing, it is all from Google in the end.)

Comment: @Jonathan I didn't find an iOS library yet.  We're about to get started with serious focus on this project next week and I will be looking much harder.  Thank you for the advice above!! Really helped!

Answer (score 1):

I did it in iOS (I can't answer the android portion) using a set of plugins, plus I inserted my own additions to make it a 1-stop setup.

1. unzip the attached zip file into your project ( https://github.com/chwagssd/qr/archive/master.zip )
2. point to <script src="path/to/decoder.js"><script>
3. Create a file input in your HTML page that has an id, say "xxx"

   ```
   <input type="file" id="xxxx">
   ```
4. Then tell the page on load to QRIfy your field! Make sure to include your callback function, which will be called with a single argument (the FULL TEXT that was scanned): QRIfy('qrCode', onQrCode);//where qrCode is the id of your

   ```
   <input type="file" id="xxxx">
   ```

I have setup a GIT repo here, grab the code (you can download the zip and put it in your javascript folder)

https://github.com/chwagssd/qr